# Enumerable objects in ViewBag in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have the below model say F:

```
public partial class F 
{
    [Key, Display(Name = "Id")]
    public int FId { get; set; }

    public int RId { get; set; }

    public int FTId { get; set; }

    public string C { get; set; }

    public string U { get; set; }

    public string D { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public System.DateTimeOffset Created { get; set; }

}
```

In the controller I have to read all the records of 'F' from database and assign those to an enumerable list of records.

For ex:

```
 ViewBag.Cs = enumerable C column items (textbox)
 ViewBag.Us= enumerable U column items (textbox)
 ViewBag.FTIDs = enumerable FTId column items (this has to be a dropdown)
```

In my I have to show

```
 @Html.Textbox(Cs);
 @Html.Dropdown(FTIDs);
```

I gave only textbox and dropdows as an example, there could be many other controls like datetimes, checkboxes etc., 
I should be able to written each column as list a in viewbag and show it in MVC View.

Can somebody advise if this achievable and how?

Many thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a viewbag for something like this - instead strongly bind your view to a model. Only use a view bag if you have something really small to pass.. anything complex you should always use a strongly typed view model, you get intellisence and its must cleaner for unit testing

View Model:

```
Public class MyViewModel
{
      public List<F> MyListOfFObjects { get; set; }
}
```

Now when you create your view you can bind it to this view model in the popup or if you don't want to recreate it simply add a reference to it at the top of your view like so:

```
@model <your project>.<folder view model is in>.<view model name>
```

for example

@model AdventureWorks.Models.EmployeeViewModel.

In your controller you simply create this view model and pass it to your view such as:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  MyViewModel vm = new MyViewModel();
  // Initialize your view model
  // Get all the F objects from the database and populate the list

  return View(vm); // now your view will have the view model
}
```

Now in the view you can iterate through this view model

```
@foreach(var fObject in Model)
{
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.fId)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.rID)
}
```

Here is a link to a list of the different @Html helpers that you can use btw

http://qkview.com/techbrij/aspnet-mvc-4

Reference for strongly binded views:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/views/dynamic-v-strongly-typed-views